# Adding up a skill

Tags: dnd-5e, skills

I think I might know the answer to this, but I am not totally sure.

My character has a strength of 7 (-2) and a current proficiency bonus of (+2). I have a proficiency in Athletics.

Adding all this information together, should I add the Strength negative modifier to the proficiency bonus for a total skill check modifier of (+0)?

Comment: Related: [Do you add Proficiency bonus AND the stat modifier to skill rolls?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56155), [Do I add negative ability modifiers to skills?](/questions/113401), [How do I calculate my skill modifier?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83930)

Comment: thank you very much MikeQ that was very much what i needed, i am finding the writing in 5e players handbook to be very disorganized and muddled, at least in how i think

Comment: @James: If one of those questions matches yours and/or answers it, let us know and we can mark the question as a duplicate of it. (Duplicates can still be useful in serving as a signpost to help others find that question in the future.)

Comment: @V2Blast yes combined they did answer my question thankyou